# Avoid lock of tables when inserting into from stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2016

I want to return an output from a stored procedure by using insert into. For performance reasons, the target table is a memory-optimized table type. 
I now figured out that while the stored procedure is running, all in the stored procedure affected rows are kept locked until the stored procedure completes.

Example:

```
insert into @ModifiedSecurities (SecurityID, AttributeTypeID)
    exec Securities.spSecuritiesImportBody
                @ProcessingID = @ProcessingID
```

During execution of `Securities.spSecuritiesImportBody` (which takes up to 10 minutes), all by `spSecuritiesImportBody` affected table rows are locked until the stored procedure completes (even the tables have nothing to do with the output of the stored procedure).

While in a single insert statement this behavior might make sense, I don't see any use of it and therefore want to get rid of these locks.

Is there any way to execute the stored procedure without creating these locks?

Here a code sample I made:

1. Execute the preparation
2. Run the code
3. Try to select from dbo.ProcessingsTesting while code is running. It won't be possible as table is locked. The lock is being create during dbo.UpdProcessing. However, for some reason, the lock is not being released.

select *
from  dbo.ProcessingsTesting

-- start of preparation

```
drop procedure dbo.UpdProcessing 
drop table dbo.ProcessingsTesting
drop procedure dbo.spSecuritiesImportBody  


go


create table dbo.ProcessingsTesting
(
    ProcessingID int,
    EndDate datetime
)

insert into dbo.ProcessingsTesting
(
    ProcessingID
)
select 1 union all
select 2 union all
select 3 union all
select 4 union all
select 5


-- stored procedure
go
create procedure dbo.spSecuritiesImportBody  
(
    @ProcessingID int
)
as
begin


    exec dbo.UpdProcessing  
        @ProcessingID = @ProcessingID


    WAITFOR DELAY '00:03:00' 


    -- return data

    select 1, 2


end


-- stored procedure

go
create procedure dbo.UpdProcessing  
(
    @ProcessingID int
)
as
begin


    update dbo.ProcessingsTesting
    set EndDate = null
    where ProcessingID = @ProcessingID


end
```

-- end of preparation

```
-- run the code 

declare @ModifiedSecurities table
(
    [SecurityID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [AttributeTypeID] [smallint] NOT NULL
)


insert into @ModifiedSecurities (SecurityID, AttributeTypeID)
    exec  dbo.spSecuritiesImportBody 
        @ProcessingID = 1
```

Comment: Show the code for the stored procedure, there is likely a transaction covering the whole thing and it would need to be adjusted to be more granular.

Comment: If the sources are disk-based, you could separate the phases. Have one phase to read from the disk-based tables in SNAPSHOT isolation level, pushing the results to an intermediate table. Then, push the intermediate result to the memory-optimized table. I wish you could perform cross-container SNAPSHOT transactions, but you can't. I have used this method successfully many times in this situation.

Comment: Not buying the lock is not released.  This example surely does not lock other tables.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you begin and commit an explicit transaction, locks will be held on the modified rows until the outermost `INSERT...EXEC` statement completes. You can add an explicit transaction to the `dbo.UpdProcessing` proc (or surround the `EXEC dbo.UpdProcessing` with `BEGIN TRAN` and `COMMIT`) to release locks on the updated rows before the `INSERT...EXEC` completes:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.UpdProcessing  
(
    @ProcessingID int
)
AS

BEGIN TRAN;

UPDATE dbo.ProcessingsTesting
SET EndDate = null
WHERE ProcessingID = @ProcessingID

COMMIT;
GO
```

Although this will provide the desired results, it doesn't make much sense to me that one would update data unrelated to the `SELECT` results in the same stored procedure. It seems the procs should be called independently since they perform different functions.

Answer (score 0):

On the procedure spSecuritiesImportBody you should change the execute update exec dbo.UpdProcessing
        @ProcessingID = @ProcessingID to 
Exec dbo.UpdProcessing  @ProcessingID because is no sense using like this.

You can not avoid the lock because the MSSQL server use lock on row, table, pages to ensure that you are not changing the data when the server is executing statements regarding that record on database.

Comment: Hi! Welcome to Stack Overflow. The original code is fine as is, because its purpose is to set the EndDate to NULL. This likely indicates that the process is actively running. Also, there are many ways to avoid locks. Check out the various transaction isolation levels for more details.

Comment: It is not possible to test or update for NULL values with comparison operators, such as =, <, or <>. To test NULL values we will use the IS NULL or IS NOT NULL operators because here are dealing with a three value field (true, false and NULL) and the NULL is need to be handled in this form.

Comment: I agree with you that are various isolation level but by default the is read commit.

Comment: That is not correct; assigning Column = NULL (or to an expression that evaluates to NULL) is the only way to make a column NULL in an UPDATE statement. The OP is not using "= NULL" in a predicate, it is part of an assignment.